# Seams are visible after texturing using UV unwrapping

Tags: uv

I'm a newbie to Blender. When I texture my model using unwrapping, the change in texture at the seams is clearly visible. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: One way is to paint over them using the clone brush, and/or put the seams in non-obvious places.

Comment: There's a few ways to texture.  If you are painting, then set your seam overdraw to zero and paint.  Save it when it's ready and load it to the model's material and then bake it to a new image.  Once baked,  the tool will spread out the edges around the seams and cleanly blend them all together so no seams are visible.  This works flawlessly so long as the baked texture is 512x512 or larger.   I set the bake tool's Margin Overdraw to 64px for the default, it always works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use texture paint mode to paint your Mesh from scratch after UV unwrapping for complete control and burden.  You may not feel like a [newbie] after that experience.